# Can't add a column by using pandas groupby.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Initially I have the following table:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(4*8).reshape(4,8),
    index=list('abcd'),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('EEEETTTT'), list('XXYYZZWW'), list('rsrsrsrs')] )
)

    E               T            
    X       Y       Z       W    
    r   s   r   s   r   s   r   s
a   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
b   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
c  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
d  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

I add a new column called `'V'` next to `( , ,'s')` multi-index column as follows:

```
    E                     T                  
    X          Y          W          Z       
    r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V
a   0   1  0   2   3  0   6   7  0   4   5  0
b   8   9  0  10  11  0  14  15  0  12  13  0
c  16  17  0  18  19  0  22  23  0  20  21  0
d  24  25  0  26  27  0  30  31  0  28  29  0
```

I ran the following code to get the above result:

```
dfl=[]
for name, x in df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1):
    index = pd.IndexSlice
    x.loc[:,index[name[0],name[1],'V']]= 0
    dfl.append(x)

pd.concat(dfl, axis=1)
```

Now I tried the following 'alternative' way to get the same result:

```
def f(x):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    x.loc[:, idx[x.name[0], x.name[1], 'V']]=0
    return x

df.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).apply(f)
```

However, to my surprise, the resulting table remains unaltered:

```
    E               T            
    X       Y       Z       W    
    r   s   r   s   r   s   r   s
a   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
b   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
c  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
d  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

The pandas groupby.appy(func) should allow the func to return a dataframe of any size or even a scalar.

Might this be a bug?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Definitely not..!

Comment: @SandeepKadapa The OP already knows how to add a column , he's just not able to do it through `apply`. Please check.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, the questions is about the strange behavior of groupby apply. I already know one solution to add a new column to multi-index dataframe as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [partial bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12652#issuecomment-197958059) related with grouping by `MutiIndex in columns`.

If working with `MultiIndex in index`, it working with small modification - removing levels used for grouping for avoid duplicates levels.

Your solution is modified by transpose for `MultiIndex in index`, apply function and transpose back:

```
def f(x):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    x.loc[idx[x.name[0], x.name[1], 'V'], :]=0
    x.index = x.index.droplevel([0,1])
    return x

df = df.T.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=0).apply(f).T.astype(int)
print (df)
    E                     T                  
    X          Y          W          Z       
    r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V
a   0   1  0   2   3  0   6   7  0   4   5  0
b   8   9  0  10  11  0  14  15  0  12  13  0
c  16  17  0  18  19  0  22  23  0  20  21  0
d  24  25  0  26  27  0  30  31  0  28  29  0
```

---

```
def f(x):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    x.loc[idx[x.name[0], x.name[1], 'V'], :]=0
    return x

df = df.T.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=0).apply(f).T.astype(int)
print (df)
    E                     T                  
    X          Y          W          Z       
    E          E          T          T       
    X          Y          W          Z       
    r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V   r   s  V
a   0   1  0   2   3  0   6   7  0   4   5  0
b   8   9  0  10  11  0  14  15  0  12  13  0
c  16  17  0  18  19  0  22  23  0  20  21  0
d  24  25  0  26  27  0  30  31  0  28  29  0
```